# Direction vector to a rotation (three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions

I'm attempting rotate an arrow on the surface of a planet to face the direction it is traveling. I can get the direction vector and the up vector from the surface normal. How would I go about turning this into a quaternion for my arrows rotation. I'm using three.js so any suggested methods they provided that I can use would be useful. Cheers.

[image]

The information I have so far.

```html
var upVector = new THREE.Vector3();
upVector.subVectors( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0), lastVec );

var dirVector = new THREE.Vector3();
upVector.subVectors( lastVec, destVec );

var sideVector = new THREE.Vector3();
sideVector.crossVectors( dirVector, upVector );

var newUp = new THREE.Vector3();
newUp.crossVectors( dirVector, sideVector );
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try (with `myDirectionVector`):

```
var mx = new THREE.Matrix4().lookAt(myDirectionVector,new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0),new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0));
var qt = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromRotationMatrix(mx);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is what I've got so far, will test with my project http://jsfiddle.net/wyb9jm5e/3/

Comment: Cool, now just update `myDirectionVector` for each frame (since right now you're forcing it to a constant), and the vector-following will be super-obvious :)